# OSB server out of memory

Tags: out-of-memory, out, osb

I have 2 cluster environment for Oracle OSB 12c. It works upto the mark with low load. However when i increase the load, it starts failing and gives Out of Memory error. This error is observed in either of the cluster there is no fixed pattern or prediction can be made about which cluster will fail. I took Thread dump but couldn't find any reason for its failing. It shows 3% thread in blocking state and 66% in waiting. None of the thread is in deadlock state. 
My question is for out of memory error, only thread dump is sufficient or Heap dump will help more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question should probably go to SF instead of SO but  I'll try to answer it anyway.

The answer to your question is yes, heap dump will help you more because it will actually show you what took up all the memory.

Comment: What is SF and SO? 
I did more reading and found that i will need below 3 things captured at the same moment. 
- Thread Dump (shows the details of process flows)
- Heap Dump (Shows the objects in Memory)
- Access Logs (shows the requests being serviced)